# Blurring (not dimming) background of activity when pop up window opens

Tags: android

How to blur the background of an activity when a pop window opens in API 14 or greater?
I know blurring is not supported in 14 or higher levels but is there any other alternative?

Comment: What exactly do you want?? A blurr effect or some trasparent black background wil do???

Comment: @Tejas I want blurr effect

Comment: fortunately it's now this easy .. https://github.com/sergei-lapin/BlurView

Answer (score 1):

## 2021 .. very easy blurring

https://github.com/sergei-lapin/BlurView

```
implementation 'com.github.sergei-lapin:BlurView:1.0.0'
```

and then on any activity you want

```
<com.slapin.blurview.BlurView
    android:id="@+id/blur_view"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:bvBlurRadius="3" />
```

I just hide `blur_view`, and then show it when the foreground activity is there.

Answer (score -1):

FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND was deprecated in API level 14.

Blurring is no longer supported.

Create a Style

```
<style name="Theme.D1NoTitleDim" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>        
</style>
```

And then on your dialog

```
dialog = new Dialog(context,styles);
```